# Transferring data from table to a bigger table with columns manipulation

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

The following problem is simplified -

I have 3 tables, table1, mapping_table and table2.

- table 1 will include 3 columns - first name , last name and date.
- table 2 will include 4 columns -  id (that gets it value from a sequence, first name , last_name_in_germen and date).
- mappingTable that will include 2 columns (last name and ast_name_in_germen).

In addition - 
date is nullable in table1 but have to has some value (like the date of today) is table2.

The problems are - 
The new table (table2) will have columns that exist in the original one (first_name), columns that will need to make some basic transformation like mapping (last_name) and adding a default value (date) and of course to use the sequence (id).

I was thinking about using a procedure with a loop but I don't know how to insert a row to the new table.

Comment: You're looking for the `INSERT` statement (`INSERT INTO table2 ...`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sound like a standard INSERT-SELECT with a join ?

```
insert into table2
select my_sequence.nextval,
       table1.first_name,
       mappingTable.last_name_in_germen,
       table1.date
from   table1,
       mappingTable 
where  table1.last_name = mappingTable.last_name
```